# ITRemoving zero from decimal part of float

Tags: java, android, floating-point

I have floats like these,

```
0.0 , 50.0 ...
```

How do I convert them to:

```
0 , 50 ...
```

I need the meaningful numbers in the decimal part stay intact;
so `13.59` must remain `13.59`.

EDIT : my question is way different from that duplicate of yours; if only you read through it you would know it.

Comment: Where is this "input" coming from? Are these strings?

Comment: @CommonsWare no; they are float as mentioned

Comment: Your problem is the output, not the input.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn the editor messed with the question;

Comment: "no; they are float as mentioned" -- if they are `float` values, then they do not have a trailing `.0`. Please feel free to post the code where you are getting these values and show where and how you are seeing the `.0`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Cmooon ! you are saying floats do not have trailing .0 ??? is this a joke ?

Comment: A `float` does not have a trailing `.0`. A string representation of a float might.

Comment: @CommonsWare mmm ; in Android ; at the end Im gonno need to use this in textviews; so I guess I have no way out of this; no ?

Comment: @CommonsWare is there anything to replace String.valueOf ? to avoid strings ?

Answer (score 1):

So there are few ways to do this.

For your way I am pretty sure you could get away with a very naive solution.

```
Number formatToInt(float floating) {
   if (Math.ceil(floating) == Math.floor(floating)) {
       return (int)floating;
    } else {
       return floating;
    }
}
```

Comment: will you explain a little ? I dont understand mFloat, is that sth I can use in Android ?

Comment: won't compile : `Math` methods won't work with `Number`, why not just using `float` ?

Comment: I think he's just using the `Number` class, but you should be able to make `num` a `float` and this should work correctly.

Comment: @Shervin4030 you are correct, it's a little confusing. I cleaned it up. Basically if the rounded up is the same as the bottom it can be safely truncated as an int, and otherwise it's a full float. I use the Number class since it's the only way to sort of treat the numbers as the same type.

Answer (score 1):

```
    package com.ceil;

    public class TestCeil {
        public static void main(String[] args) {


            double[] doubleArray = {-100.76 , 80.0 , 192.23};
            Number number;
            for(int i=0; i<doubleArray.length; i++){
                if (Math.ceil(doubleArray[i]) == Math.floor(doubleArray[i])) {
                    number = (int) doubleArray[i];

                }else
                    number= doubleArray[i];
                System.out.println(number); 
            }       


        }

    }
```

Refer the Java API. Number is the super class of both Double and Integer:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

Output can be Integer or Double depending on the decimal place value.

Comment: Im working on this; I think this is the solution; brb in 5 or 10